# Count number of sublists in list of lists

Tags: python

```
List1 = [['a','b','c','d','d'],['d','e','f','h','c'],['g','h','i','m'], ['j','k','l','m']]

counter = 0
sublist = ['c', 'd']
```

There are two `['c', 'd']` in List1.

```
List2 = [['a','b','c','c'],['d','e','f','h','c','c'],['g','h','i','m'], ['j','k','l','m']]


counter = 0
sublist = ['c', 'd']
```

There is only one `['c', 'd']` in List2.

Values could be duplicated.

What's a pythonic way to check how many sublists are in list of lists?

Comment: Have you tried exploring https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-check-if-a-list-exists-in-given-list-of-lists/ ?

Comment: @VishalDhawan I think it's a different problem. OP is not searching for exact same list but a superset of it.

Comment: OK, @user4049704. Can you decide what exactly are you asking? Is it number of subsets(the question title) or whether or not the number of subsets is equal to 2(the question body)??

Comment: Check how many sublists in list of list in counter. Others keep adding to the edit, reverting back the change.

Comment: @Asocia's answer does appear to answer the question. I've looked through all of the versions of the question in the edit history, and can't find a clear alternative question, I've looked at your [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63253886/verify-and-check-how-many-sublists-are-in-list-of-list) question, which also doesn't make things any clearer. If Asocia's answer is not what you want, you need to clarify this question. Opening another new question won't make things any clearer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `set` for this:

```
def num_of_supersets(lst, subset):
    return sum(subset.issubset(i) for i in lst)

lst = [['a','b','c','d'],['d','e','f','h','c'],['g','h','i','m'], ['j','k','l','m']]
lst2 = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f','h','c'],['g','h','i','m'], ['j','k','l','m']]

subset = {'c', 'd'}

print(num_of_supersets(lst, subset))
print(num_of_supersets(lst2, subset))
```

```
2
1
```